# Android. How to stop a method's vibrations from another method

Tags: android, android-vibration

I have a method that sends out pulses of vibrations. It uses Thread.sleep() in order to wait between each pulse. I want to input a STOP or RESET button to stop the buzzes from reaching the end of vibratorDAYONE(). I tried using v.cancel and return() but it still continues the method.

```
 public void vibratorDAYONE()
{
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    if(!v.hasVibrator())
    {
        Toast.makeText(daybuzzer.this,
                "You need to have a vibrator on your phone for this app to work.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
        {
        Toast.makeText(daybuzzer.this, "Start Running.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    v.vibrate(200); //start first
    SystemClock.sleep(2000); //Length of the first run
    v.vibrate(200);     //start second part
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    v.vibrate(200);
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    v.vibrate(200);
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    v.vibrate(200);
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
}
```

---

```
public void vibratorEnder()
{
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    v.cancel();
}
```

Comment: I am a little confused by your question. Are you calling vibratorDAYONE() in a separate thread and trying to stop it part-way through? And when/where are you calling vibratorEnder() from?

Comment: The method is called from a addListenerOnButton method. I am trying to STOP vibratorDAYONE() from completing all of its vibrations.

Answer (score 0):

Put a flag in `vibratorDAYONE()` to check against before a vibrate.  Set the flag within `vibratorEnder()`.  If the flag is set then return from `vibratorDAYONE()` instead of continuing.